# Add Hyperlinks to HTML using BeautifulSoup in Python using Anchor Text and URL stored in a CSV File

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to write a program in python beautiful soup to hyperlink words in html using the csv file with anchor_text and hyperlink

The CSV file that has 2 columns:

| anchor_text | hyperlink |
| --- | --- |
| Google | https://www.google.com |
| Bing | https://bing.com |
| Yahoo | https://yahoo.com |
| Active Campaign | https://activecampaign.com |

Here is sample HTML

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is a existing link <a class="test" href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another Google Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another lowercase bing Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another multi word Active Campaign Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

I want the output to be

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is a existing link <a href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another lowercase <a href="https://bing.com/">bing</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another multi word <a href="https://activecampaign.com/">Active Campaign</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with anchor/links on the outer loop and then break down the matching strings in the inner loop:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import element as bs4_element
import csv

html_doc = """
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is a existing link <a class="test" href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
 
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another Google Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
 
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another lowercase bing Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
 
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another multi word Active Campaign.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# read the CSV file with anchor text and hyperlinks
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  hyperlinks = dict(reader)


# from bs4 import element as bs4_element
be_navStr = bs4_element.NavigableString
 
hList = [
    (anchor_text.strip(), hyperlink.strip()) for
    anchor_text, hyperlink in hyperlinks.items()
    if anchor_text.strip() and hyperlink.strip() # no blanks
]
 

print('#'*35, 'OLD', '#'*35, '\n')
print(soup, '\n')
print('#'*75, '\n\n\n')

for txt, link in hList:
    navStrs = [
        d for d in soup.descendants if type(d) == be_navStr 
        # and f' {txt.lower()} ' in f' {d.string.strip().lower()} ' # same as
        # and f' {txt.lower()} ' in f' {d.string.strip().lower()} ' # same as
        # and (' '+txt.lower()+' ') in (' '+d.string.strip().lower()+' ')
        and (' '+re.sub('\W+',' ',txt.lower())+' ') in (' '+re.sub('\W+',' ',d.string.strip().lower())+' ') # Handles special characters like ?.!
    ]


    

    for ns in navStrs: 
        # tLen, remStr = len(txt), f' {ns.get_text().strip()} '
        tLen, remStr = len(txt), f' {ns.string} '
        remLen = len(remStr)
        # tLen, remStr = len(txt), f' {ns.text.strip()} '

        if remStr[1:-1].lower() == txt.lower():
            # to skip if it's already a hyperlink
            if ns.parent.name == 'a': 
                ns.parent['href'] = link # comment if you dont want to replace/update link
                continue 
        # Skip creating nested hyperlinks inside existing hyperlinks       
        if ns.parent.name == 'a': 
          continue 


        i = 0        
        while ' '+re.sub('\W+',' ',txt.lower())+' ' in re.sub('\W+',' ',remStr.lower()) and remStr.lower().find(f'{txt.lower()}') > -1:
            
            #print(txt.lower())
            #print(re.sub('\W+',' ',remStr.lower()))

            sInd = remStr.lower().find(f'{txt.lower()}')
            #print(remStr.lower())
            #print(sInd)
            hlTag = soup.new_tag('a', href=link)
            hlTag.append(remStr[sInd:sInd + tLen])
            #print(hlTag)
            if i == 0:
              newCont = [remStr[1:sInd], hlTag]
            else:
              newCont = [remStr[:sInd], hlTag]
            #print(newCont)

            for addn in newCont: ns.insert_before(addn)
            #print(soup)

            remStr = remStr[sInd + tLen:remLen-1]
            #print(remStr)
            i += 1

        ns.replace_with(remStr)
        #print(soup)

print('#'*35, 'NEW', '#'*35, '\n')
print(soup, '\n')
print('#'*75)
```

printed output:

```html
################################### OLD ################################### 

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is a existing link <a class="test" href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another Google Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another lowercase bing Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another multi word Active Campaign.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --> 

########################################################################### 



################################### NEW ################################### 

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is a existing link <a class="test" href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another lowercase <a href="https://bing.com">bing</a> Text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is another multi word <a href="https://activecampaign.com">Active Campaign</a>.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --> 

###########################################################################
```

This should work even with multiple matches in the same string as long as they don't overlap (like *"Google Chrome"* and *"Chrome Beta"*)

Comment: Is this Python3? I am getting an invalid syntax error in this section `anchor_text, hyperlink in hyperlinks.items()`. 

How are you reading the csv file? Are you using the code snippet I am using?

Comment: @AbhishekR Sorry I missed a `for` in that list comprehension (I've edited to fix it now), 
but yes `hyperlinks.items()` is based on the same `hyperlinks` from your snippet. That statement is the only one I typed out (to fit into your code) without testing since I got my `hList` by processing `pandas.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699446')[0].to_dict('records')`,  which is a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary...

Comment: I am now getting an error here: `and f' {txt.lower()} ' in f' {d.get_text().strip().lower()} '` 

Sorry I am unaware of this syntax.

Comment: @AbhishekR what error are you getting there? It's just normalizing the space and making it case-insensitive (so that "bing" or  "Bing" will be matched by "Bing" and "let's use Bing" and "sample bing line", but not "binged", etc), this should be ok in python3 but in case the formatted text is the issue, try *`and f' {} '.format(txt.lower()) in f' {} '.format(d.get_text().strip().lower())`* or **`and (' '+txt.lower()+' ') in (' '+d.get_text().strip().lower()+' ')`** instead

Comment: I am getting the error: `SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed`

Comment: Here is my code https://pastebin.com/6LUti6iw

Comment: @AbhishekR sorry again, I typed my last comment too carelessly - formatted text should be either like `f'{x}'` or `'{x}'.format(x)` - so it should be **`and ' {} '.format(txt.lower()) in ' {} '.format(d.get_text().strip().lower())`** - but what I was asking was what error did you get with the original *`and f' {txt.lower()} ' in f' {d.get_text().strip().lower()} '`*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250305/discussion-between-driftr95-and-abhishek-r).

Comment: Glad we could get this working